# Using masked text box to validate input

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, validation, maskedtextbox

Hi I am using the following mask string to ensure user enters a valid phone no

(99)-00000000

which should  work fine for mobile as well as regional land line numbers in Australia

However I have encountered a problem that User can get away without entring all the digits

I understand that 9 represents an optional digit between 0 and 9 and 0 represents a required digit between 0 and 9

So how come if I dont enter all last eight mandatory digits the program still display results like

(03)-6474

(03)-   63799

(02)-1 38 390

Answer (score 3):

**Because it's simply filling in the blanks from left to right as you type.** Even though the first two digits are optional, it fills them in like you've entered them with the first two numbers that you type.

If you dislike this behavior, you can easily subclass the `MaskedTextBox` control and customize how it handles keyboard input. Here are a couple of sample controls that cause the numbers to push in from right to left, as expected:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/Cool_Phone_Number_Box.aspx
- http://www.dotnetheaven.com/Uploadfile/mgold/MaskedCurrencyTextBox02252006005553AM/MaskedCurrencyTextBox.aspx

(I think the second example does a better job of explaining exactly what changes are being made to the base control, plus it allows you to see most of the relevant code without downloading the sample project.)